# What are the factor to get this ERROR `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! `?

Tags: php, http, url, httpresponse

Hi I would like to ask why i get this ERROR

I am using `file_get_contents()`

and I am currently receiving an `ERROR`

```
  failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

I would like to know how to prevent this.

I also search about curl and it is better than what I'm using right now its not matter for me if I re code or not. What i want to know is the factors why I am receiving this ERROR.

I have done searching but still i don't have clear view with this. Any comments and knowledge is well appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Does your php server allow you to include external files using file_get_contents() method.????

Comment: What's not clear about the error? The function failed to open the stream. Reasons are that the URL is invalid (or the server where you run the script simply can't resolve it) or fopen wrappers are disabled for file_get_contents. Check the examples at php.net/file_get_contents to see how you can include stream context into the function.

Comment: @RafH I don't show the url for security. but ya sometimes it works but sometime not. I wonder if i got that error, is my request does not reach the other end ?

Comment: basically I just post 2 value to the other end. http://host/controller/mthd?var1='a'&var2='b'

Comment: If your url contains parameters, check that they are properly encoded with urlencode.

Comment: @RafH I take note of that. but yeah I already used urlencode. I am reviewing every url I have since N.B said that it may be invalid, so that would be my lead right now. Thanks Guys!